# MySQL query to handle encoded characters using Regular Expressions

Tags: mysql, regex

My problem involves searching a MySQL table for a list of matching city names given an initial search string with the purpose of handling special characters such ö, etc that are encoded with an html entity (&ouml;).

Example:

There is a table called 'cities'. The column for the city name is called 'name'. There are two cities Hamberg (id 1) and Hämeenlinna (id 2) stored as H&auml;meenlinna.

Someone searches using the string "Ham". A standard query such as

```
SELECT id, name FROM cities WHERE name LIKE '%Ham'
```

will only return the first one.

I have a regex that parses out the character from the entity but it's implemented in PHP and is provided below for completeness.

```
preg_replace("/&(.).*;/", '$1', $city_name);
```

**Is there a query to include the majority of the single characters that have entities?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn’t use HTML character references in the database. Instead you should choose the right [encoding and collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset.html) and store the data in plain text.

Comment: Indeed.

If you store "ö" in mysql, you can specify collate insensitive select by doing

Select ... WHERE name COLLATE utf8_general_ci like '%o'